# Rails 4, has_many through association - finding associated objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I'm wondering why `Item.where(category: x)` isn't working for me. I expect this statement to return all items which are categorized under category x. Please see below my associations:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :categorizations
    has_many :items, :through => :categorizations
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :categorizations
    has_many :categories, :through => :categorizations
end

class Categorization < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :item
    belongs_to :category
end
```

`Category.find(1).items` returns all items for that category. Please see below, the byebug console output which demonstrates my point further. It seems like the SQl that is generated is looking for a category column in the Item table - which of course doesn't exist. Any ideas?

```
    1: class ItemsController < ApplicationController
    2:   # Returns full list of items
    3:   def index
    4:     @items = Item.all
    5:      byebug
=>  6:   end
    7: 

(byebug) Item.where(category: 1)
  Item Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "items".* FROM "items" WHERE "items"."category" = 1
#<Item::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fb5d1a37f08>
(byebug) Category.find(1).items
  Category Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE "categories"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Item Load (1.7ms)  SELECT "items".* FROM "items" INNER JOIN "categorizations" ON "items"."id" = "categorizations"."item_id" WHERE "categorizations"."category_id" = $1  [["category_id", 1]]
#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Item id: 1, title: "Gorgeous Cotton Pants", description: "Dolor dicta suscipit aut cupiditate quia officiis ...", price: 73960, status: 0, published_date: "2016-07-14 05:35:49", created_at: "2016-07-17 05:15:07", updated_at: "2016-07-17 05:15:07", seller_id: 1>, #<Item id: 5, title: "Sleek Marble Shoes", description: "Qui mollitia corporis qui placeat. Reiciendis ea s...", price: 35146, status: 0, published_date: "2016-07-14 05:45:02", created_at: "2016-07-17 05:15:07", updated_at: "2016-07-17 05:15:07", seller_id: 1>, #<Item id: 7, title: "Rustic Concrete Lamp", description: "Sit odio non exercitationem. Atque non sapiente vo...", price: 82016, status: 2, published_date: "2016-07-13 00:00:00", created_at: "2016-07-17 05:15:07", updated_at: "2016-07-17 05:15:07", seller_id: 1>, #<Item id: 10, title: "Awesome Wooden Table", description: "Possimus consequatur nulla. Quidem molestiae volup...", price: 59519, status: 2, published_date: "2016-07-09 00:00:00", created_at: "2016-07-17 05:15:07", updated_at: "2016-07-17 05:15:07", seller_id: 1>, #<Item id: 12, title: "Lightweight Concrete Bag", description: "Amet ullam assumenda eligendi consectetur quae. Bl...", price: 72081, status: 2, published_date: "2016-07-16 00:00:00", created_at: "2016-07-17 05:15:07", updated_at: "2016-07-17 05:15:07", seller_id: 2>, #<Item id: 13, title: "Mediocre Plastic Computer", description: "Excepturi modi est non qui iusto. Molestiae offici...", price: 94357, status: 2, published_date: "2016-07-15 00:00:00", created_at: "2016-07-17 05:15:07", updated_at: "2016-07-17 05:15:07", seller_id: 2>, #<Item id: 15, title: "Incredible Plastic Bag", description: "Vel voluptas ducimus soluta atque voluptatem eum. ...", price: 15661, status: 2, published_date: "2016-07-14 00:00:00", created_at: "2016-07-17 05:15:07", updated_at: "2016-07-17 05:15:07", seller_id: 2>, #<Item id: 16, title: "Lightweight Iron Watch", description: "Id sequi rerum dolor sit sunt nemo laborum. Omnis ...", price: 65306, status: 4, published_date: "2016-07-11 00:00:00", created_at: "2016-07-17 05:15:07", updated_at: "2016-07-17 05:15:07", seller_id: 1>, #<Item id: 17, title: "Rustic Linen Chair", description: "Explicabo qui ad nihil. Voluptatem placeat autem. ...", price: 39752, status: 4, published_date: "2016-07-04 00:00:00", created_at: "2016-07-17 05:15:07", updated_at: "2016-07-17 05:15:07", seller_id: 1>, #<Item id: 18, title: "Mediocre Copper Car", description: "Minus qui ut est non vero saepe. Qui sed quos et v...", price: 87765, status: 4, published_date: "2016-07-05 00:00:00", created_at: "2016-07-17 05:15:07", updated_at: "2016-07-17 05:15:07", seller_id: 1>]>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the approach for fetching associated objects with `has_many through` is to do something like:

```
Item.joins(:categories).where(categories: {id: 1})
```

I'm yet to find a better approach of doing this.